# Detect main button on Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am struggling with this, and can not find something relatively new that will work in android studio.
Can you please help me? I wish to detect main button click on my bluettoh headset that connected via Call audio (not media buttons).

Comment: Could you edit question and elaborate a bit. You don't give much details...

Comment: That pretty much it. Detect click on BT headset.

Comment: Ok, then, what have you tried ? Show us some code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect presses to headset buttons on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075909/detect-presses-to-headset-buttons-on-android)